# Search renders MathJax sections incorrectly

Tags: bug, mathjax, search

Almost exactly as the title says.

I ran a search with the search query `is:answer 0,`. Fine, search works. I got to [page 2 of the results](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=is%3aanswer%200%2c) and discovered that [HDE 226868's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/could-a-manned-maneuvering-unit-provide-artificial-gravity/6545?s=24|0.2219#6545) to "Could a manned maneuvering unit provide artificial gravity?" is rendered incorrectly.

A section that is text when you look at the actual answer is rendered in the results as MathJax, and several sections of actual MathJax are rendered as plain text.

The same thing happens on [page 3](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?page=3&tab=relevance&q=is%3aanswer%200%2c) of the same results.

Comment: Ah, my math has finally gotten me into trouble! On a more important note, this happens on quite a lot of sites. I've always thought it was just one of those things than happens with LaTeX. It also shows up on some edit histories, which can be annoying.

Comment: @HDE226868 Don't worry: [one of my answers](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11526/explaining-uphill-rivers-scientifically/11529?s=31|0.2029#11529) does the same (page 3)...

Comment: After a bit of experimentation, this seems to happen when the matched text is inside a math block, which somehow messes with the `$` delimiters.  It's as if the markup is split where the match occurs, and then each resulting block is rendered separately.  The easiest solution is probably just to turn off mathjax rendering in the preview.

Comment: I believe this is a known bug. Still, good thing bringing it up. You may also want to bring it up on [meta.se]. Flag your question for moderator attention if you want it migrated there.